# Run "bin/magento setup:upgrade" in custom.php

Tags: magento2, php

I tried to activate a module in my Magento2 system, which is on a Hosted environment without a CLI (command line /ssh shell) available.
Reading around, I've learned that this could be done by using a php file like this:

```
<?php
//system('php bin/magento deploy:mode:show');
//system('php bin/magento cache:flush');
//system('php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy');
system('php -f bin/magento setup:upgrade');
//system('php  bin/magento cache:clean');
//system('php bin/magento module:enable Ubertheme_Ubdatamigration');
?>
```

But when I try to execute this file nothing happens. Why not? In a previous test-set-up I have been able to run this without any problems? What am I doing wrong here? 
Also tried to use `magento/bin` instead but did not help either.

Comment: I think something went wrong, your pasted code is missing. Please update the question with your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `exec` instead of system, but I doubt that will work. Normally, if you don't have cli available, you don't have access to `system` or `exec` functions.
Magento 2 is not built to work with a shared host that doesn't allow you cli access.
It relies heavily on cli actions.

Answer (score 1):

This will depend a lot on your hosting provider, open a ticket with them and ask about this. Some companies disable specific commands like system() shell_exec() and exec() for security reasons.

> In a previous test-set-up I have been able to run this without any
>   problems?

You shouldn't be approaching issues like this, even between servers from the same hosting company things can and might change, not to mention you should (almost) never expect a local environment to be exactly the same as the one you are using for development (thought it's easier to work when you mimic a live environment for development)

Answer (score 0):

Try Something like this.

```
<?php
    $command = 'php bin/magento setup:upgrade';
    echo '<pre>' . shell_exec($command) . '</pre>';
?>
```

I am not sure, just try it may be it will work.

Comment: tried this but not working for me. Also with exec instead of system no result. It is on the same server as the trial I did with the same version of Magento2 although that is in its own domain. So I will have a look at the php settings on both of the domains and see what's different.

Comment: It appears that I have two versions of php running the one thats working has 7 and the one that's nog working (having system and exec not allowed) is 5.5 so I will install again with 7 and see what happens

Comment: Have you check first exec function enable from php extension ?

Comment: No did not do that. I managed to get the module working in a temp. shop on the same php7 server. Now I could import the old products etc. with the ub_data migration module. Than later on I will move the complete shop to the desired shop domain which than will be updated to run on php7 as well. Having a Magento2 shop on a Hosted environment is not funny :) I advise to avoid that if possible.